# Java run more code on a started thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a JavaFX application and in it i catch keyboard events and send to a handler function, the GUI part is irrelevant to the question and is therefor not shown here.
My question is only a threading question in java.
This is the current handler function:

```
 @Override
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    log.debug("handle getCode: {}", event.getCode());
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case NUMPAD0:
                sendCommand(HELLO);
                break;
            case NUMPAD1:
                sendCommand(TIME);
                break;
            case NUMPAD2:
                sendCommand(START_TOUR);
                break;
            case DIGIT1:
                sendCommand(JOKE);
                break;
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

And what i'm trying to achieve, is when the handler function is called if the previous "sendCommand" function is still running, the new handler run will wait until its finished, and then run.
The behavior will be like a queue of commands, though i hope i don't really need to implement a queue, but only "run more code" on the same thread, and then get the behavior i'm looking for.
Is that possible? if not what is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: You want a single threaded `ExecutorService` http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Comment: And just for the record: in 2017, using bare metal threads is like the very last design option you pick when implementing a "more parallel" thingy.

Comment: @GhostCat - It's been 2018 for almost 8 full months. But your point still holds true (perhaps even more so).

Comment: Stupid auto fill ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ExecutorService` with a single thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()), it will handle this for you. The task will be put into a queue if the previous one is still running.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    log.debug("handle getCode: {}", event.getCode());
    executor.execute(() -> {
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case NUMPAD0:
                sendCommand(HELLO);
                break;
            case NUMPAD1:
                sendCommand(TIME);
                break;
            case NUMPAD2:
                sendCommand(START_TOUR);
                break;
            case DIGIT1:
                sendCommand(JOKE);
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ive put the initialization of Executor in the class builder, and changed the function to exactly what you wrote here. And it still execute concurrently. how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Strand` (additional info [here](http://www.crazygaze.com/blog/2016/03/17/how-strands-work-and-why-you-should-use-them/). It is a wrapper around an `Executor` ensuring only one task submitted through it (the strand) is running at a time.

Example implementation:

```java
public class Strand implements Executor {
        // this queue may be extended to swallow repeating events
        private final Queue queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

```
    private final AtomicBoolean scheduled = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final Executor delegate;
    private final Runnable THE_TASK = () -> {
        scheduled.set(false);

        final Runnable task = queue.poll();
        if (task != null) {
            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                ; // do something meaningful here, e.g. redispatch to some exception handler
            } finally {
                schedule();
            }
        }
    };

    public Strand(Executor delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    private void schedule() {
        final boolean needToSchedule;
        synchronized (this) {
            needToSchedule = ! queue.isEmpty() && scheduled.compareAndSet(false, true);
        }

        if (needToSchedule) {
            try {
                delegate.execute(THE_TASK);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) { // failed to schedule with the delegate
                scheduled.set(false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        queue.add(task);
        schedule();
    }
}
```

```